# Create a dataframe when given a column number

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I give a column number like any number 'n' ,it should create a dataframe with those many number of columns. Currently what usually is as below.

```
val list = sc.parallelize(List((1, "b", "c", "d"))).toDF()
```

This will give 4 columns but if I want to pass the column number as paramater and create a dataframe.

The number of columns with any data in it or an empty dataframe, Please let me know if there a way to do it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the number of columns `n:Int`, this will return an empty dataframe:

```
def createEmptyDf(n:Int) = {
  val df = spark.emptyDataFrame
  (1 to n).foldLeft(df){ case (resDf, i) => resDf.withColumn(s"$i", lit(null))}
}
```

After seeing your note, you can also do it with the following groupby/pivot to transpose:

```
val df = (1 to n).map(i => (i, 0)).toDF()
  .groupBy($"_2").pivot($"_1")
  .agg(first(lit(0)))
  .drop($"_2")
```

Comment: cool thanks, can we fill the dataframe with some say "0" value for all the columns in it ? in the same step if possible

Comment: @Babu yes I posted an update. I couldn't figure out a way to do it without aggregation. There might be an easier way to transpose a dataframe.